# How to mimic LINQ's query method for macro's key-value?

Tags: best-practices, programming, key-value, code-review

Inspired by LINQ's query method, such as

```csharp
deck.Take(randomCount)
    .Where (card => card.Suit == "Hearts")
    .Skip(2)
    .Take(5)
    .OrderBy (card => card.FaceValue);
```

The `deck` which is an object of a class that inherits `IEnumerable` will have the LINQ's query methods.

I want to apply this to LaTeX macros, for example, `\includegraphics` as follows.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[viewport={10cm 10cm 10cm 10cm},clip,width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics
    .viewport{10cm 10cm 10cm 10cm}
    .clip{}
    .width{3cm}
    .file{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

### Questions

1. How to create a macro that behaves as follows?

   ```
   \includegraphics
       .viewport{10cm 10cm 10cm 10cm}
       .clip{}
       .width{3cm}
       .file{example-image-a}
   ```

   Remember that we can omit some of the keys if not needed. For example,

   ```
   \includegraphics
       .width{3cm}
       .file{example-image-a}
   ```

   can be invoked.

   And the order is not important, for example,

   ```
   \includegraphics
       .file{example-image-a}
       .width{3cm}
   ```

   can be invoked as well. But at least one is mandatory, in this case, `file`.
2. What is the disadvantage of implementing this style of coding?

Comment: For TeX, it is disaster if there is no clear end of the parameter list (i.e. a character which always occurs at the end, like `]`). If you add that, then your syntax is just a minimal variation of the usual key-value syntax.

Comment: if you have an ending `;` and use parentheses `(` and `)` rather than braces, as in your initial model, then as [Stephan Lehmke](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/12850/stephan-lehmke) says, this is a rather easily equivalent variant of the `[key1=value, key2=value, ...]` syntax.

Comment: @jfbu braces are better because they can be nested. To have parentheses in an argument, one would have to write `({...})`.

Comment: @StephanLehmke to put commas in an argument of usual `key=value` syntax, one similarly needs braces. I mentioned `(` and `)` because this is *much* easier to parse than obtaining the `{..}` things which are in the OP code only identified as occurring last before `space+dot`.

Comment: @jfbu what about `#{` syntax?

Comment: @StephanLehmke indeed.. forgot about that one. One may then even drop the dots from the input syntax, for example using `#1#2{` to get in `#1` the first character of the key skipping the previous space and in `#2` the rest, so the key is `#1#2` and then one picks the value and proceeds to the next key with suitable end test. But one will need some steps to allow optional space before the opening brace as it will end up in the brace delimited parameter. Anyhow this has already been treated in `key=value` things. One can even do that expandably.

Comment: (I meant, one could even allow spaces within the keys and get rid expandably of the last space before the brace, or the `=` sign, keeping intact the previous ones)

Comment: There seem to be only disadvantages and no advantages to doing this. It's like asking to use a German grammatical construct in the middle of an English sentence. It's not that either German or English are bad on their own but randomly mixing the two grammars is confusing for humans even if you can get it to work technically.

Comment: If you want order to not be important, you have to arbitrarily specify the order in which keys are executed. if `angle=90 width=5cm` means the same as  `width=5cm angle=90` (whether you use a dot or a comma syntax) then you have to say whether width means the initial width or the final width, and how it interacts with `scale=50%`

Comment: `width`, `height`, `scale` can be defined as mutually exclusive keys. It means the last wins.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote several similar systems, none of them for LaTeX though, probably for the good reason raised by David Carlisle, that using such *macro interfaces* in LaTeX would confuse users and cancel any benefits you could have from such an interface.

Let me review one of these systems, it is carefully described so that you can easily adapt these techniques to your case or other similar situations.

### hbox-like interfaces in plain TeX with getoptk

One such system is the `getoptk` package which you may find in [`tex/plain/contrib/getoptk.tex`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/contrib/getoptk) and that were described in [TUGboat 32-2](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101grunewald.pdf), it defines new macros in plain TeX which enable the user to define commands mimicing the interface of `hbox`, `hfill` etc.

### getoptk in action!

Using these macros, you could define a version of `\includegraphics` which you could use like this:

```
\includegraphics
  viewport{10cm 10cm 10cm 10cm}
  clip
  width=3cm
  {example-image-a}
```

As you see, we crucially need a non optional argument to mark the list of our options.  Preparing the definition of that revolted teen `\includegraphics` requires the definition of an option dictionary:

```
\newgetoptkdictionary{includegraphics}
\defgetoptktoks{viewport}{\def\includegraphics@viewport{#1}}
\defgetoptkflag{clip}{\cliptrue}
\defgetoptkdimen{width}{\imagewidth=#1}
```

The `defgetoptk*` calls define new optional arguments and behaviours. The replacement texts of these behaviours are saved as the macros

```
\getoptk@behaviour@includegraphics@viewport
\getoptk@behaviour@includegraphics@clip
\getoptk@behaviour@includegraphics@width
```

We now need to define the `\includegraphics` macro itself, it looks like

```
\def\includegraphics{%
   \setgetoptkdictionary{includegraphics}%
   \getoptk\includegraphics@M
}
```

and the previous call to our `\includegraphics` would be replaced by

```
\includegraphics@M{%
  \getoptk@behaviour@includegraphics@viewport{10cm 10cm 10cm 10cm}
  \getoptk@behaviour@includegraphics@clip
  \getoptk@behaviour@includegraphics@width{3cm}%
}{example-image-a}
```

Neat, isn'it?  The package is a bit long and uses some mid-level programming techniques in TeX (`edef`, `futurelet` and registers, essentially).

### Other similar macros

I am the author of a hobby TeX format, branded [Bhrìd TeX](https://bitbucket.org/michipili/bhrid) — I am looking for a new, funnier, name, by the way — which I started in 1999 after reading David Solomon's advanced TeX book — I decided to move to the non-advanced one a year later. But enough archeology!

If you enjoy reading french, please open [the programmer's manual](https://bitbucket.org/michipili/bhrid/downloads/bhridman-v1.0.pdf) you should go the the section 2.6 and look for the family of macros `\getoptspec`.  They are similar to `getoptk`but work with macros instead of keywords, which is of course easier to write!  If you feel evil minded enough to play with the catcodes of `.` `(` and `)` and a few others you may even let TeX understand that statement

```
deck.Take(randomCount)
    .Where (card => card.Suit == "Hearts")
    .Skip(2)
    .Take(5)
    .OrderBy (card => card.FaceValue);
```

But doing such tricks is not the LaTeX way.